# printf on Linux vs Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, printf

Here is some C code :

```
int i;
printf("This text is printed\nThis text is not until the for loop end.");
for (i = 5; i > 0; i--)
{
    printf("%d", i);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Why is the rest of the text after the `'\n'` not printed before the `for` loop start? Even the printf inside the for loop is only printed after the loop end.
If I put a `'\n'` at the end of the text, it prints, but I do not want a new line.

This only happens on Linux and not on Windows (just changed sleep(1) to Sleep(1000) and added windows.h).

Comment: It's been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: Windows and Linux have very different console output drivers. In Linux, the output is being buffered until the `\n` occurs in the case of your program.

Comment: Why do you think you don't want a newline at the end of your output?  There must be a reason you (and a lot of other Windows programmers) don't output it, but it seems weird to Unix programmers (e.g. me) — just as outputting a newline seems weird to Windows programmers, I guess.  On Unix, you do it to make sure the output is produced — so there's a sound reason to do it.  On Windows, presumably, the default mode corresponds to non-buffered so all output is generated as the call ends.

Comment: I did not want the new line, because I wanted the loop to output on the same line each turn. I was used to see it working on Windows and I was surprised to see that on Linux. I knew it was something about buffering. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by output buffering. When you call printf, the output isn't printed immediately. It is written to a buffer to be output sometime in the future. Usually a `\n` character causes the buffer to be flushed automatically. You can also flush the stdout buffer manually:

```
printf("This text is printed\nThis text is not until the for loop end.");
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 2):

The buffer of `stdout` is not specified by the C standard. But POSIX implies(not requires) that usually `stdout` is line buffered when it's connected to a terminal, is fully buffered otherwise.

Linux follows this POSIX convention but Windows does not. You can change the default behavior using `setvbuf` or use `fflush` to flush the output, that's guaranteed by the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

Look up [`setvbuf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html)
 and `_IONBF` vs `_IOLBF` vs `_IOFBF`.  By default, when the output is to a terminal, the output is line buffered (`_IOLBF`).  This means that output only appears when a newline is included.  `_IONBF` is non-buffered, sometimes reserved for standard error (though that too can be line buffered).  `_IOFBF` is fully-buffered; the output won't appear until the internal buffer is full, or you explicitly `fflush()` the output (or, sometimes, if you read from standard input).  If you write to a pipe, or a file, the output will normally be fully buffered.

In general, you should expect to end outputs with a newline if you want to see them in a timely fashion — Windows-based examples to the contrary notwithstanding.  (It is a common meme on Stack Overflow that reasonably reliably identifies when a program is written for Windows.)